# Problems deleting cookies, won't unset

Tags: php, cookies, unset

I've tried searching the php manual and internet on how to delete cookies and I've tried it the exact same way they all say:

```
setcookie("name", '', 1);
```

or

```
setcookie("name", '', time()-3600);
```

But when I check the cookies in the cookies dialog in Firefox, it's still there with the same value.
I set this cookie using the following line:

```
setcookie("name", $value, time() + 259200, $path);
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497501/cookie-wont-unset) question on stackoverflow:
, but none of the answers solved the problem. I also tried putting all paramaters in, like the author said, but it had no effect.

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: dots in cookie names are replaced by _ chars - this might cause some problems

Comment: First, make sure that the cookie view (e.g. in Firefox) is actually refreshed. Then, do what you already did, but pay attention to all the properties which *must be the same* for the "set" and the "unset" or "delete" operation. Further, you might use something like `$cookie->delete();` from https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie for more convenience.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[The manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set with. If the value argument is an empty string, or `FALSE`, and all other arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client. This is internally achieved by setting value to 'deleted' and expiration time to one year in past.

So also make sure that `$path` is specified correctly -- **also when deleting it**. For instance, if the cookie was specified in a subdirectory, you may not be able to delete it from either the parent or children directories (or both).

I'm not entirely sure how the permissions work, but you might want to use the Web Developer Toolbar to view what the *path* is of the cookie you are attempting to delete.

Comment: I'm checking the Firefox Cookies dialog, and the path I'm using to set the cookie is the same as the path I'm using to unset it. But the address where I try to unset the cookie is not the same as the path I set the cookie to.
I also found out that I can change the value of the cookie, if the expiration date is in the future. If I use a value in the past, nothing happens. Weird?

Comment: After several minutes of tests, I couldn't make it work! No cookie deletion at all. Now I know : use setcookie with the same parameters as you used at creation time, $path,$domain & so on. setcookie($name,NULL,-1) isn't enough!
Thank you for your remark!

Comment: FINALLY!!! I Installed a Chrome extension to find out what the path was for the cookie set by my app - and then I could unset it perfectly at last! Brilliant answer!

Comment: Was racking my brain on this, thanks for this answer.

Comment: Brilliant - I'm reading JS-centric docs and flailing for hours - then I find this answer and it's working in 5 minutes!

Comment: For people who used setcookie without path when setting cookie in PHP, simply use ```setcookie("name", 'value', 1, '/');```

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned it (or maybe I missed it), but **domain is important too**!  If you are on sub-domain.example.com, and the cookie is from .example.com, then you need to explicitly set the domain parameter, otherwise it will assume the current domain and it won't work.

```
setcookie('cookiename', FALSE, -1, '/', '.example.com');
```

Sub-domains value will not clear cookies from parent domain.

Comment: This helped me solve my issue. Let me share the full code if (isset($_COOKIE['auth_cookie'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['auth_cookie']);
    setcookie('auth_cookie', false, -1, '/', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
}

Answer (score 15):

Ok, I really don't understand, but it works now. The magic code is:

```
setcookie("name", '', 1, $path);
```

Haven't I already tried that??! Whatever, it works now. Thanks for your help, people!

Comment: It works if your cookies was ''. It's important that the cookie has the same value of when you setted it.

Answer (score 7):

If you **delete** cookie for the specific path and your **path** parameter ends with the **trailing slash '/'** then it will work in Firefox and IE, but won't work in Chrome and Opera. If there is no trailing slash then it will only work in Chrome and Opera.

So you should use both:

```
setcookie('cookiename', '', time() - 60*60*24, $chatPath); // WebKit
setcookie('cookiename', '', time() - 60*60*24, $chatPath . '/'); // Gecko, IE
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I cannot believe that this is still going on in 2021. To remove a specific cookie I had to use your suggestion which I found after hours messing about. I know use the following to remove a specific cookie (for future users)
`unset($_COOKIE['name']); setcookie("name", '', 1, '/'); setcookie("name", '', 1, '');`

Answer (score 2):

I tried using

```
setcookie("name", "", -1);
```

and on my server with Apache/PHP5 it cleared the cookie (at least a var_dump($_COOKIE) showed an empty array).

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if your script already send its HTTP headers?

```
if (headers_sent()) {
  trigger_error("Cant change cookies", E_USER_NOTICE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me:

```
setcookie("brownie","",1,'/');
unset($_COOKIE["brownie"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like is said in the correct answer (I want it to send an updated one), to unset, every parameter used to set the cookie is necessary, even **secure** and **httponly**

Set

```
setcookie("name_cookie", $name_value, 0, '/', $domain, false, true);
```

Unset

```
setcookie("name_cookie", '', time()-1000, '/', $domain, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the time to a small value and using a value for cookie?

```
setcookie("name", 'n', 1);
```

Comment: I found out that I can actually change the values if the expiration date is in the future. Then the value doesn't matter. But using '1' as time doesn't seem to work, as does time()-3600.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me as well one in ten times though. I guess its a problem with the way we code.

This is my code

```
setcookie("token", "", time() - 36000, "/");
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference? I also tried using the path parameter, if that's what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean to say even I get the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to using

```
ob_start();
```

at the firts l

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I found that, for whatever reason, echoing something out of logout.php made it actually delete the cookie:

```
echo '{}';
setcookie('username', '', time()-3600, '/');
```

Comment: Strange, should be totally opposite of that. Deleting should be possible only before first output, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you saved the cookie in a different path than you're trying to delete/uset it in.

Go into eg. Chrome cookie settings and check the cookie path, then add the path to the setcookie command, and delete it like this:

```
setcookie( "my_cookie_name","",1,'/mypath');
```

Trying to delete or unset a cookie that is saved in the wrong path will not work and can be very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a custom function in global core functions file like global.php

```
function delete_cookie()
{
unset($_COOKIE['cookiename']);
setcookie('cookiename',NULL,time()-3600, '/');
return true;
}
```

and use this function at the top of the html code like

```
include('global.php')
if(isset($_GET['delete_cookie']))
{
delete_cookie(); //if you want to pass the parameters into the function also possible like delete_cookie(param1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**set a cookie**

setcookie('cookiename', $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
// 86400 = 1 day

**unset cookie**

setcookie('cookiename', '', time() - 3600, "/");

No need to panic. Just copy function you use to set cookie and now minus the time. Do not get confuse, make it easy and clear.

Comment: I'm using literally the same function call to delete the same cookie and it once works and other time it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

this is my experience with cookie that, the cookie may not be deleted from the client machine until the browser window (that we use to see existing cookie) is closed. So close that window and the try your code.

- All params must be there while deleting that was there in creation
- time must be in past
- value must be '' (empty)
- folder path must be same at of creation time

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised no one has posted this yet, but this works perfectly for me:

**To CREATE or CHANGE cookie by name:**

```
$_COOKIE['myCookieName'] = 'I can be changed to whatever u want';
```

**To DELETE a cookie by name:**

```
unset($_COOKIE['myCookieName']);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var remember = $.cookie('auto_login');
if (remember == 'true') {
    var username = $.cookie('username');
    var password = $.cookie('password');
    $('#username').val(username);
    $('#password').val(password);
}

$('#logsub').click(function (event) {
    if ($('#auto_login').is(':checked')) {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        // set cookies to expire in 14 days
        $.cookie('username', username, {expires: 14});
        $.cookie('password', password, {expires: 14});
        $.cookie('auto_login', true, {expires: 14});
    } else {
        // reset cookies
        $.cookie('username', null);
        $.cookie('password', null);
        $.cookie('auto_login', null);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.