# PHP Cookies Not Unsetting [Unusual Situation]

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with some cookies not unsetting. I have had a look through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856366/problems-deleting-cookies-wont-unset) but all the answers have not worked.

I have 13 cookies in total, which I need to clear to test occasionally. When I unset them using:

```
setcookie("name", "", time() - 3600, '/');
```

What makes this unusual, is that using the same code with a different name unsets 10 of 13 cookies, leaving 3 still set... All the cookies are created at the same time, and I am trying to unset them all at the same time. I have checked the cookie names which all match what is stored on my PC.

As stated, I have tried all the answers in the post linked above, but none have worked. The cookies are set and unset from within the same directory, just a different file of which permissions are the same level.

Any suggestions?

(Not sure if it matters, but I'm using Chrome on Mac)

Example:
Setting cookies during login (I've dumbed it down to the 4 key cookies I need)

```
if($pass == 1) {
    setcookie('auth_code',$no_generator,$cookie_expire,'/');
    setcookie('username',$_POST['username'],$cookie_expire,'/');
    setcookie('admin',$admin,$cookie_expire,'/');
    setcookie('login_time',$date,$cookie_expire,'/');
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = "true";
    header('Location: /logs.php');
}
```

Unsetting Cookies:

```
setcookie("admin", "", time() - 3600, '/');
setcookie("login_time", "", time() - 3600, '/');
setcookie("username", "", time() - 3600, '/');
setcookie("auth_code", "", time() - 3600, '/');
```

$cookie_expire is set to: `$cookie_expire = time() + (21*365*24*60*60);`.

Comment: Can you create an **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**?

Comment: Check you have spelt the names correctly

Comment: Edited Question and all names have been double checked, even used an online comparison tool just in case.

Comment: Also, all the code there is directly copied from the live files, so you can see the spelling of the names match etc..

Comment: Those are the cookies, that will remain unset ?

Comment: @Kkinsey Nope, just added `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` to the removal file, still won't remove the cookies..

Comment: @frz3993 Yes, that's correct. Except the "login_time", that unsets fine.

Comment: And please check in chrome when you unset the cookies, the `can't be unset cookies` expiry date, do they change ?

Comment: @frz3993 Not sure how I would check... But, I use the same code, just different names for all my cookies, the others unset, so not sure why these wouldn't too..

Comment: Open the developer tools, click the Resources tab and in the left most pane choose to collapse the cookies and select the website. It should show all the cookies with expiry date if they are not session cookies.

Comment: @frz3993 All set to expire `2037-07-16T12:31:33:622Z`

Comment: When you unset it, does the time change?

Comment: @frz3993 No, remains the same.

Comment: are you sure that you are unsetting all cookies **before** sending any content to the client (except the response header of course) ?

Comment: I would suggest to install LiveHTTPHeaders (it's a plugin) on Firefox and look at the response header when the page that is supposed to unset the cookies is sent.

Comment: @frz3993 The file literally consists of php tags, a load of `setcookie("auth_code", "", time() - 3600, '/');` etc lines of code, and thats it... Nothing at all is sent to the browser, except a HTML link to my `check_cookies` page... Which is after all the PHP stuff..

Comment: *"The file literally consists of php tags"* that means that you open and close php code blocks with `<?php` and `?>` several times ? In that case you may inadvertitely be sending content (even a space) to the browser while unsetting cookies. In that case just begin the script with `<?php` and never close the block. If you have to send some content `echo` it

Comment: No, there's a single `<php` and ends with a single `?>`

Comment: I thought in somewhere in your application you have the cookies being set back after the unset. So when you set the cookie you will have the initial expiry time, when you run the unset php script the expiry time will change because it is being set again. If this is not the case, this is a weird behavior.

Comment: @frz3993 Nope, I manually run the cookie removal file as i don't want the users to be able to delete their cookies unintentionally. Although, I'm starting to believe more and more that i've messed up somewhere and potentially done something tiny that's causing the issue. Just another learning curve for me I guess! Thanks for all your help anyway, give me a shout if anything else comes to you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code work well in my localhost.
did you try set cookies name as array? i did a little modification for my local:

```
<?php
    $pass=$_GET['pass'];
    if($pass == 1) {
        $a='A';
        $cookie_expire = time() + (21*365*24*60*60);
    setcookie('coo[auth_code]',$a,$cookie_expire,'/');
    setcookie('coo[username]',$a,$cookie_expire,'/');
    setcookie('coo[admin]',$a,$cookie_expire,'/');
    setcookie('coo[login_time]',$a,$cookie_expire,'/');
    //$_SESSION['logged_in'] = "true";
    header('Location: ./log.php');
}
```

then unset using looping

```
foreach($_COOKIE['coo'] as $k=>$v){
    setcookie("coo[$k]", "", time() - 3600, '/');
}
```

Just in case,

> ```
> Note from php.net
>
> If the PHP directive register_globals is set to on then cookie values will also be made into variables. In our examples below,
> ```
>
> $TestCookie will exist. It's recommended to use $_COOKIE.

Comment: I'm willing to try this one, but I'd like to understand more how it works (I'm relatively new to development..) For example, setting cookie names as arrays.. Is the only benefit that it would mean a single line to remove all cookies? Or are there other benefits? Also, the first line of your code `$pass=$_GET['pass']` - I'm not sure where this is set, or how it works. Could you explain? Thanks.

Comment: about the arrays, it's just simplify if we have lots of cookie variables. And about the $_GET['pass'] and variable $a, it's just my example to try your code instead of creating new form using $_POST data.