# Deleting a cookie with Expires / Max-Age of Session

Tags: php, session, cookies

When I look in my chrome dev tools (Cookies section) you have 5 relevant columns:
Name, Value, Domain, Path and Expires / Max-Age
I have a cookie that I can't delete with and Expires / Max-Age of Session. The odd thing is that when I inspect with x-debug it doesnt show up under $_SESSION it shows up under $_COOKIE.

I first tried deleting with JS, this worked on my local environment but when I pushed it up to a staging server the cookie wasnt being deleted.

Next I tired deleting it with PHP since it is my understanding that session cookies cant be deleted with js but when trying to delete the cookie with setcookie, or something like

```
    setcookie (session_id(), "", time() - 3600);
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
```

I still have no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems deleting cookies, won't unset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856366/problems-deleting-cookies-wont-unset)

Answer (score 0):

Set the time to Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT. I believe it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `session_write_close()` after the `session_destroy()` may be an issue. Have you try to use only `session_destroy()`?

You can use `unset($_COOKIE[session_name()])`; to delete the cookie of the session

Comment: Still no luck, I find it odd I can delete with js on local but not my staging server. Think there could be some weird server settings?