# Removing cookie not working in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

It's kind of weird, but I set a cookie with:

```
setcookie('auth', 'ok', time() + 3600, "/");
```

**Result:**

```
Name:   auth
Content:    ok
Domain: --.com
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Tuesday, July 11, 2017 at 11:00:23 PM
Expires:    Wednesday, July 12, 2017 at 12:00:23 AM
```

It works fine, but when I want to remove this cookie:

```
setcookie('auth', 'ok', time() - 3600, "/");
unset($_COOKIE['auth']);
```

there is no change in the result, and the cookie is not removed, and I still got this cookie in my browser.

The cookie is created in this URL:

> auth.php?action=confirm

and call a function with `ajax`:

> model/auth.php

And it should remove it in this URL:

> auth.php?action=logout

But it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Try to set value as `null` when erasing cookie and time to `-1` but any time in the past should work.

Comment: Have you tried `setcookie("auth", "", time()-3600);` ? defining empty value

Comment: @JTC yes, i also tried `null` but not working , empty and null.. still have this cookie

Comment: @tilz0R you mean `setcookie('auth', null, time() - 1, "/");` ? still not working

Comment: @JTC not possible because read this topic before. Im sure `domain` and `path` are same.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to delete a cookie is to clear both of the $_COOKIE value and browser cookie file:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['auth'])) {
  unset($_COOKIE['auth']);
  setcookie('auth', '', time() - 3600, '/'); // Empty value and old timestamp
}
```

Comment: did it change browser cookie file to null?

Comment: no nothing changed. i insert this `if (isset($_COOKIE['auth'])) { echo "ok";}` and it print `ok` i mean it detect that cookie but can't delete or change.

Comment: should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856366/problems-deleting-cookies-wont-unset

Comment: i read this topic before, already read again, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are outputting some data before destroying the cookie.

Try to check this, and before any output use this code:

```
setcookie("auth", "", time()-3600);
```

With this `$sent = headers_sent($file, $line);` you can see if some data have been outputted before you tried to destroy the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the path is also correct.
You can do this by opening microsoft edge -> settings -> cookies and site permmision -> see all cookies -> search for the domain name of your site -> click the drop down and find the cookie name -> view the imformation.
Under the information you will find path. The path is not always "/"

Then just replace "/" with the path you find there.
example if the path is "/abc"

```
setcookie('auth', null, time() - 3600, "/abc");
```

You might be able to find cookie info on other browsers but I only found how to do it on microsoft edge.